# CAShapeLayer changes in tableview reloadData

Tags: ios, uitableview, cashapelayer

I have a table view with custom cell which in its view, i add shape to it. It shows shapes correctly at the first time, but after reloadData shapes changes and doesn't show correctly. why is that happen? (with reloadData order of rows changes)

```
let cPath = UIBezierPath()
    cPath.move(to: centre)
    cPath.addArc(withCenter: centre, radius: radius, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: arc + startAngle, clockwise: true)

    // circle shape
    let circleShape = CAShapeLayer()
    circleShape.path = cPath.cgPath
    circleShape.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    circleShape.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    // add sublayer
    cell.pasokhView.layer.addSublayer(circleShape)
```

Comment: Where do you add the shape layer? The problem might come from the fact that cells are re-used.

Comment: I'm adding it to a view in my custom tableView cell. I'm thinking cell reuse, too. how can i fix it? @ThomasKrajacic

Comment: I bet you @ThomasKrajacic is right. This can get tricky, not sure what your data structure looks like for your tableview. An Idea would be to draw it the first time the cell is row is queued and then store it in a data structure for later use.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could prevent the shape layer from being added multiple times (assuming that is the problem here).

- The most simple one would be to check if your view's layer already has a sublayer (via its `sublayers` property) before adding your shape.
- You could also just delete all sublayers before adding the new one.
- Another option would be to just set a bool flag property to `true` when you add your layer, and before adding it always check if this flag is false.

I am not aware of any method that runs only once for a table view cell (`awakeFromNib` certainly is called multiple times when cells are re-used)